# wrong partitions with matlab's cvpartition

Tags: matlab, function, partitioning

I am having trouble with the cvpartition function of Matlab. I want to perform a 5-fold cross-validation (for classification) with a dataset that has 134 instances from class 1 (negative) and 19 intances from class 2 (positive). 
With 5-fold CV one should have something like 4 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 3 positive instances partitioned along the 5 folds or close to that (5 - 4 - 3 - 4 - 3 would also be OK). I make 30 repetitions of the 5-fold CV and sometimes Matlab builds partitions like 1 - 5 - 5 -4 - 4 or even 5 - 5 - 5 - 4 - 0 , that is, on of the folds has no positive instances! How is this possible and how can I correct this? At least it should guarantee that the two classes were always represented in each fold...

This brings me problems when trying to compute PRecision, Recall, F-measure and so on...

LS

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the stratified form of cross-validation that `cvpartition` provides?

Use the second syntax described in the documentation page, i.e. `c = cvpartition(group,'kfold',k)` rather than `c = cvpartition(n,'kfold',k)`. Here `group` is a vector (or categorical array, cell array of strings etc) of class labels, and will stratify the selection of observations into folds rather than just splitting everything randomly into groups.

Comment: Yes, I am using the startified form of CV...
Here is part of the code

cv=cvpartition(classes,'k',k);
            
            for f=1:cv.NumTestSets
                tr=data(cv.training(f),:);
                te=data(cv.test(f),:);
(...)

Comment: Hmm, wierd. If I do this: `a = [ones(134,1);ones(19,1)*2]; c = cvpartition(a,'k',5); for i = 1:5 disp(sum(a(c.test(i))==2)); end` I reliably get a very even split at about 4-4-4-4-3. I'm not sure what you're doing that's introducing any difference.

Comment: In fact weird. I ran your code example using my data and I got this strange behaviour. My group vector contains zeros and ones and the result is 0-0-0-0-0...when I sum 1 to the group vector (and thus one class is coded 1 and the other 2 as in your example) I got 4-4-4-4-3...

Comment: If your group vector is coded with zeros and ones, instead of ones and twos like my example, the equivalent of my test code would use `for i = 1:5 disp(sum(a(c.test(i))==1)); end`.

Comment: Yes, I've corrected that after I sent the message. It works ok.